# Complex SQL query Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql

```
 Lesson.joins(:custom_attributes).where("custom_attributes.attribute_name_id = 103 AND cast(custom_attributes.value as float) BETWEEN 0 AND 61").where("custom_attributes.attribute_name_id = 103 AND cast(custom_attributes.value as float) BETWEEN 0 AND 61").where("attribute_name_id = 112 AND custom_attributes.value LIKE '%55%'")
```

Above is an example of what I am trying to achieve. When I try:

```
Lesson.joins(:custom_attributes).where("custom_attributes.attribute_name_id = 103 AND cast(custom_attributes.value as float) BETWEEN 0 AND 61").where("custom_attributes.attribute_name_id = 103 AND cast(custom_attributes.value as float) BETWEEN 0 AND 61")
```

It returns the right record. But when I chain the query with another, it doesn't get any records even though there are records that satisfy both conditions. I think it has something to do with selecting the custom_attributes.attribute_name_id?

Comment: Have you already debugged the sql that is generated? You can check it on the logs, or you can add a: **.to_sql** at the end. Can you update your question with both sql queries, and identify which is the mysql part that you are not expecting so we can help to build the right query?

Comment: You're trying to get a row where `attribute_name_id` is 103 and 112 at the same time, that's not how a db works. You either need a subquery or a self join.

Comment: Thought that may be the case. Are you able to provide a basic example?